# Parents date of marriage

Tags: marriage-records

How can I find the date for my parents' marriage? They were married in Virginia.

Answer (score 1):

Recent records are held by the Virginia Department of Health. The [Office of Vital Records website](https://www.vdh.virginia.gov/vital-records/) says:

> Death, marriage, and divorce records become public information 25
> years after the event. Vital records are available to immediate family
> members only: mother, father, spouse, child, brother, sister, and
> grandparents with valid identification.

Some records since 1936 are available to search in a database on Ancestry: [Virginia Department of Health](https://www.ancestry.com/collections/search/va/doh). The relevant collections are:

- Virginia, U.S., Marriage Records, 1936-2014
- Virginia, U.S., Marriage Registers, 1853-1935

If you cannot find their marriage by searching in vital records indexes, try other record types. The FamilySearch Research Wiki article [United States Record Finder](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/United_States_Record_Finder) suggests:

- Vital Records
- Church Records
- Census
- Town Records

If those searches are unproductive, try:

- Newspapers
- Bible Records
- Cemeteries
- Military Records
- Probate Records
- Naturalization and Citizenship
- Land and Property

Research librarians in the towns where your parents live might be able to help; public libraries often have files of newspaper clippings and other loose items called vertical files, local histories, etc.

Consider also that your parents might have married elsewhere but you were told otherwise.  When families live close to the state border, it's not uncommon for people to have a 'destination' wedding in a picturesque venue that happens to be across the state border.

Bad indexing might be another reason you might not be able to find a marriage.  If you're searching online, look for instructions on how to use wildcards. If the online database is derived from a printed source and the index has been generated via Optical Character Recognition, the entry you seek may have been skipped or combined with an entry above or below. When images of the indexes are available, always look at the images to make sure you haven't missed an entry because of an indexing or OCR problem.

Other resources:

- Cyndi's List: [Vital Records: Virginia](https://www.cyndislist.com/us/vital/va/)
- FamilySearch Wiki: [Virgina Vital Records](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Virginia_Vital_Records)
- FamilySearch Wiki: [Gretna Greens in the United States](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Gretna_Greens_in_the_United_States)